# Quero criar uma calculadora em Python com construtor, mas quando crio um objeto diz que a classe não esta definida

Tags: python-3.x

```
class Calculadora:

    def __init__(self, numero1, numero2):
        self.numero1 = numero1
        self.numero2 = numero2

    def soma(self):
        soma = self.numero1 + self.numero2
        print("A soma é: " + soma)

    def sub(self):
        sub = self.numero1 - self.numero2
        print("A subtração é: " + sub)

    def mult(self):
        mul = self.numero1 * self.numero2
        print("A multiplação é: " + mul)


    calculadora1 = Calculadora(4, 5)

    calculadora1.mult()
```

Answer (score 1):

Acontece que a instância do objeto está dentro da classe, basta retornar a indentação

```
class Calculadora:

    def __init__(self, numero1, numero2):
        self.numero1 = numero1
        self.numero2 = numero2

    def soma(self):
        soma = self.numero1 + self.numero2
        print("A soma é: " + str(soma))

    def sub(self):
        sub = self.numero1 - self.numero2
        print("A subtração é: " + str(sub))

    def mult(self):
        mul = self.numero1 * self.numero2
        print("A multiplação é: " + str(mul))


calculadora1 = Calculadora(4, 5)

calculadora1.mult()
```

Também fiz a conversão para `string` do resultado, pode ser que dê erro ao juntar a `string` com numeral

Answer (score 1):

```
class Calculadora(object):
  
    def soma (self,primeiro_valor,segundo_valor):
        
        self.primeiro_valor = primeiro_valor
        self.segundo_valor = segundo_valor
        return  self.primeiro_valor + self.segundo_valor;
        
    def sub (self,primeiro_valor,segundo_valor):
        
        self.primeiro_valor = primeiro_valor
        self.segundo_valor = segundo_valor
        return  self.primeiro_valor - self.segundo_valor;
        
        
    def mult (self,primeiro_valor,segundo_valor):
        
        self.primeiro_valor = primeiro_valor
        self.segundo_valor = segundo_valor
        return  self.primeiro_valor * self.segundo_valor;
 
        
    def div (self,primeiro_valor,segundo_valor):
        
        self.primeiro_valor = primeiro_valor
        self.segundo_valor = segundo_valor
        return  self.primeiro_valor / self.segundo_valor;
```

Eu fiz sem construtor e deu certo